# Android admob failed to load ad

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to ad adds to my application, I saw somewhere this error can mean my code is fine it's just admob doesn't have an add to return but actually I am using testing mode so I can't understand what's wrong. Here's my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main3con"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main3">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my Activity :

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
public class main3 extends Activity {
    private AdView mAdView;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR")
                .addTestDevice("207B846CF80A463F4B3150638CF7D2D0") // I don't know if it's okay to show.
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(request);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mAdView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        mAdView.pause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mAdView.destroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

My strings.xml (if needed):

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Deck Randomizer - Clash Royale</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
</resources>
```

And I also added Internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml, And Google play services in gradle.build (I added into Module.app and not project, is it fine?)

I deleted some parts aren't connected to the ads, if something else needed, just say. Thanks.

EDIT: LOGCAT filtered to ads:

```
04-27 17:27:29.101 2171-2171/com.clash.deckrandomizer D/DynamitePackage: Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl
04-27 17:27:29.481 2171-2171/com.clash.deckrandomizer I/Ads: Starting ad request.
04-27 17:27:30.011 2171-2291/com.clash.deckrandomizer W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 2
04-27 17:27:30.011 2171-2171/com.clash.deckrandomizer I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
04-27 17:27:30.011 2171-2171/com.clash.deckrandomizer W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 2
```

Comment: in the logCat, try to filter for "ads". do you see any traces? if so, post the traces here for us to debug. sometimes when the internet connection is slow (e.g. on a 3G network), the ads don't show.

Comment: @AngelKoh Added :)

Comment: error code 2 (either internet connection is slow causing a timeout, or the time between device and google's server time is too different). more details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22136119/admob-banner-not-working-on-mobile-data

Comment: @AngelKoh I don't know, tried multiple devices and Emulator too..

Comment: are they all using the same network to connect to the internet? I have the same issue sometimes when my test device switches to the 3G network. do you have another ISP/data network to connect to the internet?

Comment: @AngelKoh Tried WIFI and 4G, Both phones are galaxy s6's if it matters, I can get my hands to LG G4, any difference? also I noticed when running on Emulator the error code changes from 2 to 0, meaning?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110398/discussion-between-angel-koh-and-davidbalas1).

Comment: @AngelKoh Thanks for solving my problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should post your `build.gradle` file. Make sure you properly reference the dependency in your app's `build.gradle` file. Open `YourProject/app/build.gradle` and make sure you've specified like this:

```
...
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    }
...
```

Comment: I added this actually.